# Copying a std::string to char*

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a copy of a std::string to a char*. This is my function and its seen result:

```
void main()
{
std::string test1;
std::cout << "Enter Data1" << std::endl;
std::cin >> test1;
char* test2;
test2 = (char*)test1.c_str();
std::cout << "test1: "<< &test1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "test2: "<< &test2 << std::endl;
}

Enter Data1
Check
test1: 0x7fff81d26900
test2: 0x7fff81d26908
```

I am unsure if a copy has been created or both of them are pointing to the same location.
How to confirm this?

Comment: Please be noted, test1 is a class, test2 is a pointer, it's totally different. test1.c_str() return the pointer of the member of test1. Alexis's answer is correct way to copy whole data to a new pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just copying the adress and using a C cast in C++
use [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) instead

```
char* test2;
test2 = strdup(test1.c_str()); //free it after
```

or

```
   char *test2 = malloc(test1.size());
   strcpy(test2, test1.c_str());
```

Comment: Not a standard function. Anyway this is a duplicate and has been answered before.

Comment: Your edit is wrong. Also in C++ we use `new`, `delete` and `std::copy` not `malloc`, `free`, and `strcpy`.

Comment: yeah and you don't use char* but vector of char, string or any objects, but the question is about char*

Comment: How can you use c_str as size for malloc?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit sorry forgot the strlen, edited now

Comment: Seriously, `strlen`? Do you realise the string already knows its own size?